# How to fire a deferred in Twisted?

Tags: python, twisted, deferred

I'm working with twisted. I'm a little bit confused about using deferred objects.
I see me correct result in this deferred but I can't work with it.

For example

```
def hello(defer):
    print(defer)
```

Just printest me

> Deferred at 0x24dv5f5 current result: 44

How can I access this result?

**Update**

This is my code where I try to fire the deferred

```
    def handleLoginFailed(self, sid, args):
        d = defer.Deferred()
        d.callback(sid)

        def writeLoginFailed(sid, args):
            print("sid:", sid)
            self.simpleQuery(
                """
                INSERT INTO auth
                    (session, success, username, password, timestamp)
                VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, FROM_UNIXTIME(%s))
                """,
                (sid, 0, args['username'],
                    args['password'], self.nowUnix()))
        d.addCallback(writeLoginFailed(sid, args))
```

Answer (score 9):

```
d = Deferred()
d.callback("the result")

def handleTheResult(result):
    print "The Deferred fired, its result is:", result
d.addCallback(handleTheResult)
```

Comment: The [documentation](http://twistedmatrix.com/documents/12.3.0/api/twisted.internet.defer.Deferred.html#callback) says `callback(self, result)`, indicating that `result` is the 2nd parameter. However, the same documentation fails to explain `self` so one has to be suspicious that something is amiss.

Comment: If you don't understand what "self" means in that context, you need a basic refresher on Python syntax, not Twisted.  http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#random-remarks

Comment: I don't know why but this is not working. I'll paste my code. Look at the update

Comment: It's not working because you are *calling* `writeLoginFailed`, not *passing* `writeLoginFailed`.  You need to change your code to say `d.addCallback(writeLoginFailed, args)`.